# KOrganizer (KDE) listing on Ubuntu Software listing

Tags: korganizer

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 on separate physical HDs.  With 14.04 I can get KOrganizer listed and have it installed and running.  However, with 16.04 I cannot find that program on the software center to install it.  Is KOrganizer incompatible with 16.04?

Comment: It's in `universe`. Have you enabled `universe` in your 16.04?

Comment: And run `apt policy korganizer` to check. Note the spelling.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments KOrganizer is in the `universe` repository and can be installed like any other software.

Make sure you have the aforementioned repository enabled. It can be checked in System Settings > Software Properties. Enable it if not already.

Then, in Terminal,

```
sudo apt install korganizer
```

Comment: I finally found KOrganizer but the references to Universe are nowhere to be found. Further, KOrganizer doesn't work properly.  I've come to suspect that my installation may be part of the problem although no errors pop up.  I'll get a new disk.

Comment: If you had open System Settings > Software Properties you'd see right in the first tab `main`,  **`universe`**, `restricted` and `multiverse` as this are the the official repositories. If my answer was useful please consider accepting it. The problems you may be experiencing now have nothing to do with your original question.